# Extract specific object contain specific string using Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have this field, and I am using underscore js

I'm trying to access the `_id` field if it contain `.tgz`

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>_.contains() function</title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src= 
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js" > 
        </script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src= 
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore.js"> 
        </script> 
    </head>        
    <body> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var people = [ 
                {"id_": "sakshi.tgz"}, 
                {"id_": "aishwarya.zip"}, 
                {"id_": "ajay.tgz"}, 
                {"id_": "akansha.yml"}, 
                {"id_": "preeti.json"} 
            ] 
         console.log(_.where(people, {id_: "sakshi.tgz"})); 
        </script> 
    </body>  
</html>
```

I only know how to do the **exact** match.

```
console.log(_.where(people, {id_: "sakshi.tgz"}));
```

## Expected Result

As you can see, I'm trying to get 2 of them that end with `.tgz`.

Any hints for me ?

Fiddle : https://codepen.io/sn4ke3ye/pen/KKzzzLj?editors=1002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string, and you want to know whether its last four characters are equal to `'.tgz'`, this is one possible way to do it ([MDN: slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)):

```
aString.slice(-4) === '.tgz' // true or false
```

If that string is the `id_` property of some object, just reference the `id_` property first and then call `slice` on it:

```
someObject.id_.slice(-4) === '.tgz' // true or false
```

This is something we want to do with every object in a collection, so it is our [iteratee](https://underscorejs.org/#iteratee). In order to have it applied repeatedly, we wrap it into a function:

```
function idEndsWithTgz(obj) {
    return obj.id_.slice(-4) === '.tgz';
}
```

Now we can use this iteratee with [`_.filter`](https://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
console.log(_.filter(people, idEndsWithTgz));
```

For a more thorough introduction to Underscore, you can also refer to another recent answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63088916/1166087

Answer (score 1):

```js
let newArr = people.filter(obj => obj._id.substr(obj._id.length -4) === ".tgz");
```

I use `filter` and `substr` JavaScript built-in methods of sorting the `_id` that ends with `.tgz`.